# English Translation of "Umay" (feeling tired of eating the same food)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, translation

As a Filipino-Canadian, I often go to Filipino gatherings with lots of tasty Filipino food. In some cases, we eat so much food that we become full; however, in other cases, we say that we are "umay"... **we simply feel tired of eating the same food and wish to eat no more, but it's not the same as full**.

People become "umay" when they eat so much of the same food without becoming full, but still end up not wanting to eat it anymore

Is there an English verb/adjective for this? Something I could say during non-Filipino gatherings?

Comment: Maybe just *bored*?

Comment: Also, when you're at that point, would you eat other food, or just cease eating?

Comment: Languages all have their quirks; no doubt there are many things you can say in one word of English that would take several words in Tagalog, Ilocano, or what have you, and words in each of those languages that take half a paragraph of English to express.

Comment: How is 'umay' pronounced?

Comment: One could say: "*The food is [a little] too [rich](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rich) for my taste*", or that they can't eat any more because they "*...feel **queasy**...*". Among relatives or friends, you'd say "*I couldn't manage another bite*", or "I'm stuffed"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say ***fed up*** covers it partially.

> Unable or unwilling to put up with something any longer
>
> <sub><sup>Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fed+up</sup></sub>

As an example:

> I'm fed up with eating the same food.

Also, you can say:

> I'm sick of eating the same food.

Comment: But `fed up` is quite negative, isn't it? It doesn't seem like they actually feel fed up, no? Although thinking about the meaning, that matches what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Neeku: OP is asking for a negative feeling also.

Answer (score 14):

If I were tired of eating tofu dishes, for example, I would say that I am tofu'd out.

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of a word or phrase that could be applied generically, but as you note you can indicate that you are *[tired of](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tire-of)* or *[bored with/of/by](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/bored-by-of-or-with-american?q=bored%20of)* a particular food; you've had *enough* of it.

More emphatically, you might be *[sick of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sick?q=sick%20of#sick__15)* that food, having *had plenty* of it, indeed having *[had your fill](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fill?q=have%20my%20fill#fill__23)* of it. You're *[weary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/weary?q=weary)* of it, even *[fed up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fed-up)* with it, because you've *eaten your weight* of it.

But the above can be interpreted as saying the food is not generally appetizing, rather than that you've gorged on it. Thanks to the constant pathologization of our emotions and to phrases like *[metal fatigue](http://materials.open.ac.uk/mem/mem_mftext.htm)* entering mainstream use, one could more jokingly describe being "sick of" a food as an actual kind of sickness:

> It's dinnertime, but after 4 hours at the Mediterranean Festival, I've developed a serious case of schwarma fatigue.
>
> I overdosed on unagi at the all-you-can-eat sushi restaurant.

Answer (score 4):

“Umay” has no English equivalent. “Umay” is more than just fed up or sated. Umay is when you’re eating a particular food (say, roast pork), and your taste buds are looking for something more, a different taste to break the sameness of the roast pork. You’re not full, nor are you bored with the taste of roast pork. You just want a taste break, or a taste filler, so that when you go back to the roast pork, there’s renewed vigor in your taste buds. That’s why we have “atchara,” (pickled papaya) which is “pampatanggal umay” (anti-imay) served during big meals.

Comment: Sometimes elaborate meals include between-course small servings of sorbet, which are called palate cleansers. A related idea.

Comment: @Xanne - "Palate cleanser" is the function of the sorbet -- not what the course is called. ("Entremet" or, "Intermezzo", in French and Italian cuisine, respectively,

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Filipino and I agree with the word fed up. That's closer to what we mean by "*umay*". We say "*umay*" when we had enough of something, either pertaining to a certain food, attitude of a person, or even to the person itself.

Answer (score 2):

"Being fed up with eating the same food" implies that you have been eating that food for, say, days. As in: I don't feel like eating chicken yet again.

In contrast, *umay*, from my understanding, means that you are saturated with a certain taste. For example: you were given a big slice of chocolate cake... you've eaten most of it but really can't get yourself to eat any more because it feels like you would, like KuyaDan says, start feeling nausea otherwise.

"Overkill" might be a possible translation, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just add that *umay* doesn't always indicate fullness (well, at least in my house). It could also indicate greasy and fatty foods when you've eaten enough to feel dizzy of the taste but you're not necessarily full.

So, in this case, we use *umay* in the same way as the word *nauseating* but the word itself isn't always used as *nauseating*.

I think that it's pretty hard to translate it since it can be used in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting there may be no direct translation with the full nuances of *umay*, the word ***glut*** or ***glutted*** may be close:

> I'm *glutted* with roast pork.
>
> I've had a *glut* of roast pork.

While it still has a general sense of "being full", the first four forms below (when used with an object) focus on too much *of that thing*, and not just being full in general.

> **glut**
> *verb (used with object)*, glutted, glutting.
>
> 1. to feed or fill to satiety; sate: *to glut the appetite*.
> 2. to feed or fill to excess; cloy.
> 3. to flood (the market) with a particular item or service so that the supply greatly exceeds the demand.
> 4. to choke up: *to glut a channel*.
>
> *verb (used without object)*, glutted, glutting.
>
> 5. to eat to satiety or to excess.
>
> *noun*
>
> 6. a full supply.
> 7. an excessive supply or amount; surfeit.
> 8. an act of glutting or the state of being glutted.
>
> [*Source: Dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/glutted)

Answer (score 0):

I would use "satiated" to describe the fatigue from a certain type of food or even a whole feast!  Satiety contextually gives a sense of having anything initially well desired but getting too much of it as to begin resisting it.  The feeling of having eaten too much fatty or oily food, for example. That is the effect of the Filipino word "umay" (pronounced ooh-mai, with mai pronounced like the mai in siomai), which could be both a noun (satiety) or adjective (satiated).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word ***jaded***:

> **jaded**
> <sub>*adjective*</sub>
>
> bored or lacking enthusiasm, typically after having had too much of something.
>
> (From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/jaded))

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is no exact translation of umay in English, this is something unique in Philippine culture.  The best way is to describe what is umay to be clear and understood by non- Filipino audience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing [food fatigue](https://www.preppedgirl.com/uncategorized/food-fatigue/food-fatigue-4-easy-ways-to-fight-it/). Looks like it also means naumay.

Comment: Can you explain what naumay means?